# Quantiles Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, quantile

What isn't working:

```
def ATVScore(x,p,d):
    if x <= d[p][0.25]:
        return 4
    elif x <= d[p][0.50]:
        return 3
    elif x <= d[p][0.75]: 
        return 2
    else:
        return 1



df_segmented['atv_quartile'] = df_segmented['Average_Transaction_Value'].apply(ATVScore, args = ('Average_Transaction_Value', quantiles,))
```

What is working:

Quantiles def:

```
quantiles = df_final_table.quantile(q=[0.25,0.5,0.75])

quantiles = quantiles.to_dict()

def RScore(x,p,d):
    if x <= d[p][0.25]:
        return 1
    elif x <= d[p][0.50]:
        return 2
    elif x <= d[p][0.75]: 
        return 3
    else:
        return 4
    
def FMScore(x,p,d):
    if x <= d[p][0.25]:
        return 4
    elif x <= d[p][0.50]:
        return 3
    elif x <= d[p][0.75]: 
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

df_segmented['recency_quartile'] = df_segmented['recency'].apply(RScore, args = ('recency', quantiles,))
df_segmented['frequency_quartile'] = df_segmented['frequency'].apply(FMScore, args = ('frequency', quantiles,))
df_segmented['monetary_quartile'] = df_segmented['monetary'].apply(FMScore, args = ('monetary', quantiles,))
```

Data:
[image: Data]

ERROR:

[image: Error]

Comment: So what's the question? What do you actually want?

Comment: Error indicates that you don't have column `Average_Transaction_Value` in your `df_segmented`

Comment: The same way I have recency_quartile, frequency_quartild and monetary_quartile I want to have atv_quartile. I used the same approach as for recency and frequency but I am not sure why it isn’t working. Error is also attached

Comment: @Sociopath yes that’s what I understood but that column is there

Comment: @SanaShah what is the value in `quantiles` variable passed into apply?

Comment: @Sociopath quantiles = df_final_table.quantile(q=[0.25,0.5,0.75])
quantiles = quantiles.to_dict()

Comment: You wrote that you created *quantiles* from *df_final_table*, but you failed to provide its content. Provide just the **content** of *quantiles* instead of the way how you created it.

Comment: That advice helped! I didnt have an 'average_transaction_value' column in df_final_table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is most likely in the content of *quantiles*.

After you created this variable, print its content.
Probably it contains something like:

```
{'recency':   {0.25: 350.0, 0.5: 500.0, 0.75: 600.0},
 'frequency': {0.25: 370.0, 0.5: 520.0, 0.75: 620.0},
 'monetary':  {0.25: 390.0, 0.5: 540.0, 0.75: 640.0}}
```

(as values of each embedded dictionary I passed arbitrary values).

Now when you apply *ATVScore* with remaining arguments as
*'Average_Transaction_Value'* as *p* and *quantiles* as *d*, this function:

- attempts to execute `if x <= d[p][0.25]:` (almost at the end of your
  StackTrace),
- executing `d[p]` it tries to find *'Average_Transaction_Value'*
  key in *quantiles*,
- since *quantiles* does not contain this key, a *KeyError* exception
  is thrown.

Add *'Average_Transaction_Value'* key to *quantiles*, with a value of
something like *{0.25: 410.0, 0.5: 560.0, 0.75: 660.0}}*
and your code should run with no error.